# How to not wrap row on browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap to structure the page like this. Each row has the same structure.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working fine and looks like this.

```
<------col-md-6------><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1->
<------col-md-6------><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1-><-col-md-1->
```

But when the browser resizes horitontally (gets narrower). The pages becomes the following:

```
<------col-md-6------>
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<------col-md-6------>
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
<-col-md-1->
```

So how do I make it so that it does not stack? And have to be scrolled?

I have tried applying the following css but does not work.

```
.row {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 1250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want it so that phone do wrap, but a browser window that is resized does not?

Comment: Your "md" rules apply to medium size screens and **larger**.   By default fields are stacked.

Comment: @Goose I do not want the row to wrap no matter how large or small the browser window is

Comment: @PM77-1 good catch, so how do I get around that

Comment: If you want to force your grid on reasonably small screen sizes then use "sm" classes.

Comment: @b11 is my answer of any help? Recently updated.

Comment: @hungerstar yes it's great thank you. `jcruz` answered first so I accepted his answer

Comment: @hungerstar I have upvoted your answer

Comment: @b11 no worries, when I asked an answer hadn't been accepted and thought some part of your question might have gone unanswered so I was  just checking in if I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the corresponding grid column classes for each screen size. For example, using .col-xs-* and .col-sm-* for extra small and small screens as described in the Boostrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes it so that the elements stack on top of each other on page resize

Comment: My bad, I had the sm/xs in my example set to 6 where you need 1; i've updated my answer to reflect what you need. The important thing is to understand that you need to use sm and xs columns to target such screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `col-xs-` instead of `col-md-`. Your columns will get super skinny as a single column (width 12.5%) of a `300px` viewport/parent element width is `37.5px` (not a lot of room for content). Adding a minimum width for `.row` might be required depending on your needs.

When using the medium grid classes a class like `.col-md-6` is set to `width: 50%;` for viewport sizes 992px and up. Below that the element (normally a DIV) no longer has a width applied to it and reverts to being a block level element that takes up the full width of the parent element. Hence the wrapping of your elements.

Using a smaller grid class like `-xs-` lowers the threshold for how small of a screen that an element will have a width set on it.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
</div>
```

Example using a horizontal scrollbar if not enough space is available for content in the columns.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.fixed-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.fixed-container .row {
  min-width: 1250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">col-xs-1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```